# read from file and output in kodi play

Tags: python, scripting, kodi

am trying to read content of disc01.nfo and then play it

i have tried

`link ='bluray://udf%3a%2f%2fC%253a%255cetc%255cdisc1.iso%2f/BDMV/PLAYLIST/00000.mpls'`

and that works yet its not working when i try reading the disc1.nfo
with this `bluray://udf%3a%2f%2fC%253a%255cetc%255cdisc1.iso%2f/BDMV/PLAYLIST/00000.mpls` in it

```
import xbmc

    # read nfo file for episodes (Show\S01\) 
    # in this format
    file = open('C:\etc\disc1.nfo', 'r')
    print file.read()

    #link='bluray://udf%3a%2f%2fC%253a%255cetc%255cdisc1.iso%2f/BDMV/PLAYLIST/00000.mpls'
    #xbmc.Player().play(item=file.read())
```

am trying to map disc01.iso/BDMV/PLAYLIST/00000.mpls to TV Show\S01E01 in kodi

yet am getting stuck pretty early on in my test script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a .strm file to play.

Open blank txt file put you link and call it AAA.strm. Now you can run it.

.NFO is only for Information to get from IMDB or TVDB.

Comment: to make it more simpler for me, how can i play the file in the folder, not the whole path to the iso file? like disc01.iso not path/to/disc01.iso